# plotly overrules ggplot2's scale_fill_manual's labels

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, r-plotly, ggplotly

I have a sample data set containing a end of week date and a churn value, either be negative or positive. In ggplot2 I use the `scale_fill_manual()` on the sign of the value as group.
This works perfectly fine showing the colors for positive versus negative values. Also the labels get rewritten according to the labels provided. However if I simply make it a plotly graph I lose my labels and they are set back to the -1, 1 factors instead. Does plotly not support this and if so is their another way to get this done

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

dt <- structure(list(date = structure(c(18651L, 18658L, 18665L, 18672L, 
18679L, 18686L, 18693L, 18700L, 18707L, 18714L), class = c("IDate", 
"Date")), churn = c(-3.27088948787062, -0.582518144525087, -0.125024925224327, 
-0.333746898263027, -0.685714285714286, -0.340165549862042, 0.0601176470588235, 
-0.119351608461635, -0.0132513279284316, -0.011201854099989)), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))

plot_ggplot <- ggplot(dt, aes(x = date, y = churn * 100)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes(fill = factor(sign(churn)))) +
  scale_fill_manual(
    values = c("#4da63f", "#e84e62"),
    breaks = c("-1", "1"),
    labels = c("Growing base", "Declining base")
  ) +
  ylim(-75, 25) +
  labs(
    title = "Weekly churn rate",
    fill = "Legend"
  )
plot_ggplot
```

[image: ggplot output image]

```
plot_ggplotly <- ggplotly(plot_ggplot)

plot_ggplotly
```

[image: plotly output image]

Comment: Define the fill variable as a factor before passing the data to ggplot.

Comment: Does that means that ggplotly does not support this and that I need to work around it adding a factor column with the correct label names in my table?

Comment: Yes, as far as I know it is not supported and that is the most straight forward workaround.

Comment: Thanks, I think I will manage to work around it like that, but before doing that I always want to be sure if my workaround is actually needed and not due to my lack of knowledge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this do the trick?

```
dt$base = ifelse(sign(dt$churn)>0, "Growing base","Declining base")
plot_ggplot <- ggplot(dt, aes(x = date, y = churn * 100)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes(fill = base)) +
  scale_fill_manual(
    values = c("#4da63f", "#e84e62"),
    ) +
  ylim(-75, 25) +
  labs(
    title = "Weekly churn rate",
    fill = "Legend"
  )
plot_ggplot
plot_ggplotly <- ggplotly(plot_ggplot)
```

[image]

edit: I just read the comment, I think it is what was suggested

Comment: Thanks to work out the suggestion given, it solves indeed the outcome of my plot. also good to know I actually have to use this work around as ggplotly does not support the breaks / levels like ggplot does in `scale_*_manual()`